# Java - How to set ExitCode in SpringBatch Application

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-batch

I am making a Spring Batch application where I have tasklet and processor. 
In the processor I throw Exceptions, and my needs is to System.exit() the application according to the exceptions I thrown.

But I don't know how to do this.

Thanks for your reply

Answer (score 5):

> my needs is to System.exit() the application according to the exceptions I thrown

I would not recommend to call `System.exit` to kill your application as this will kill your job without gracefully shutting down the process and cleaning up resources.

If you use the `CommandLineJobRunner`, you can provide a custom `ExitCodeMapper`. See here: https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/4.0.x/reference/html/job.html#exitCodes

If you use Spring Boot, you need to call `System.exit` with the return value of `SpringApplication`. You can find an example here: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/master/spring-boot-samples/spring-boot-sample-batch/src/main/java/sample/batch/SampleBatchApplication.java#L67 and more details in the reference documentation here: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-application-exit

Now to be able to customise the exit code of the job when an exception occurs in the processor, you need to:

- propagate this information at the job level. This is possible by getting access to the job execution context in your processor and then use it in a job listener
- use a custom `ExitCodeGenerator` to get access to the job execution through the `JobExectutionEvent` sent by Spring Boot and customise the exit code

Here is an example:

```
@Configuration
@EnableBatchProcessing
public class MyJob {

@Autowired
private JobBuilderFactory jobs;

@Autowired
private StepBuilderFactory steps;

@Bean
public Step step() {
    return steps.get("step")
            .<Integer, Integer>chunk(2)
            .reader(new ListItemReader<>(Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 4)))
            .processor(new ItemProcessor<Integer, Integer>() {

                private StepExecution stepExecution;

                @BeforeStep
                public void beforeStep(StepExecution stepExecution) {
                    this.stepExecution = stepExecution;
                }

                @Override
                public Integer process(Integer item) {
                    if (item.equals(3)) {
                        stepExecution.getJobExecution().getExecutionContext().put("failure", "item not accepted");
                        throw new IllegalArgumentException("3 is not accepted");
                    }
                    return item;
                }
            })
            .writer(items -> {
                for (Integer item : items) {
                    System.out.println("item = " + item);
                }
            })
            .build();
}

@Bean
public Job job() {
    return jobs.get("job")
            .start(step())
            .listener(new JobExecutionListenerSupport() {
                @Override
                public void afterJob(JobExecution jobExecution) {
                    String failure = jobExecution.getExecutionContext().getString("failure");
                    if (failure != null && failure.equalsIgnoreCase("item not accepted")) {
                        jobExecution.setExitStatus(new ExitStatus("Not Accepted"));
                    }
                }
            })
            .build();
}

@Bean
public ExitCodeGenerator exitCodeGenerator () {
    return new MyExitCodeGenerator();
}

static class MyExitCodeGenerator implements ExitCodeGenerator, ApplicationListener<JobExecutionEvent> {

    private JobExecution jobExecution;

    @Override
    public int getExitCode() {
        if (jobExecution.getExitStatus().getExitCode().equalsIgnoreCase("Not Accepted")) {
            return 42;
        }
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public void onApplicationEvent(JobExecutionEvent jobExecutionEvent) {
        this.jobExecution = jobExecutionEvent.getJobExecution();
    }
   }

}
```

If you run this with:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class DemoExitCodeApplication {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.exit(
            SpringApplication.exit(
                SpringApplication.run(DemoExitCodeApplication.class, args)
            )
    );
   }
}
```

The exit code of the JVM is 42, which is what was set when an exception is thrown in the processor.

Comment: There is a similar question to this one, I'm adding it here for reference: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7879550/spring-batch-how-do-i-return-a-custom-job-exit-code-from-a-steplistener

Answer (score 1):

You can find a good explanation in this [article](http://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-exit-codes). One way to do it is to provide the `ExitCodeExceptionMapper` bean to map the exception to some specific exit code:

```
@Bean
ExitCodeExceptionMapper exceptionMapper() {
    return exception -> {
        if (exception.getCause() instanceof NumberFormatException) {
            return 80;
        }
        return 1;
    };
}
```

**UPDATE**

This small example should make it clear:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class DemoApplication implements CommandLineRunner {
  @Bean
  ExitCodeExceptionMapper exitCodeExceptionMapper() {
    return exception -> {
      if (exception.getCause() instanceof MyException) {
        return 10;
      }
      return 1;
    };
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.exit(SpringApplication
        .exit(SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args)));
  }

  @Override
  public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
    throw new MyException();
  }

  private class MyException extends RuntimeException {}
}
```

Then I execute the following commands to run the app:

```
mvn package
java -jar target/demo-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

After this commands I can check the exit code with the following command for windows:

```
echo Exit Code is %errorlevel%
```

And it returns:

```
Exit Code is 10
```

Comment: Hello Sergii, thanks for your reply,
I tried to add the ExitCodeExceptionMapper in my Application class but it seems the getExitCode is never triggered ...

Comment: I have only a main method where I do the SpringApplication.run() who runs my BatchConfiguration class.

Comment: @Neewd I have added a complete sample.