# is it possible to restart a job after stopping?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-batch

I am working on a project in which I can hit maximum 15k hit a day to Google API. So I want to stop the job after 15k and resume it next day. Please let me know how can I do the same.

Please let me know how can I achieve the same. Right now I am thinking of using quartz scheduler to schedule the job every day.

If anyone needs full explanation, I can explain it more.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can stop a step execution (and its surrounding job) using [`StepExecution#setTerminateOnly`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/4.1.x/api/org/springframework/batch/core/StepExecution.html#setTerminateOnly--). So in your case, you can use for example a `ItemReadListener#afterRead` or `ItemWriteListener#afterWrite` that has access to the step execution and set the `terminateOnly` flag after processing 15k items. When you stop the job gracefully like this, its status will be `STOPPED` and you will be able to restart it again the next day as you mentioned.

You can find an example in the [Stopping a Job Manually for Business Reasons](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/4.1.x/reference/html/common-patterns.html#stoppingAJobManuallyForBusinessReasons) section of the reference documentation.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, Mahmoud. Can you please share some docs related spring batch with quartz. So that I can read more about scheduling.

Answer (score 0):

I had something similar where I needed to stop a 24/7 job 5 minutes before server maintenance was scheduled to start.

The easiest I found was to use the Reader and return null to indicate the job should stop.  In your case, return null when 15k API requests were processed.

This will likely mean you'll need a bean (could be just an `AtomicInteger`) available to the Reader and updated by the Processor.  But also a Job Listener (sorry, I don't have the code) which also knows about the bean.  If the maximum is reached the [Listener sets up a custom job exit value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7879550/spring-batch-how-do-i-return-a-custom-job-exit-code-from-a-steplistener) to be returned to the scheduler when the job stops. The scheduler has to be configurable enough to know the particular exit value means to start the job again the next day. (Any other non-zero value was treated as an error.)

This means there is a small possibility the job hits 15k but also that it is the last item, so the job is scheduled again for the next day even though there is nothing more to be processed.  It shouldn't matter though - the job will start the next day and stop immediately with a normal complete status so the scheduler will not schedule again.

Comment: Thanks, Andrew. Can you please share blog or doc ref for quartz scheduler with spring batch.

Comment: I am not familiar with quartz.  You'll need to research quartz capabilities or possibly create a new question and tag quartz.